# YOUTUBE API : Retrieve video keywords

Tags: php, youtube, xml-parsing, youtube-api, keyword

Recently youtube decided to output video keywords only to authenticated developper.

I register a developper key

and I'm try to get a XML that I'll parse
by requesting

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/COwIYbYQUrQ?key=MY_VERY_LONG_DEVELOPER_KEY

The output XML still send me

```
<media:keywords/>
```

What am I missing in the process?

Thanks

Comment: YouTube changed the feed a while back to *only* return the keywords when your request is authenticated as the video owner: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_media:keywords

Answer (score 1):

YouTube makes the `<media:keywords />` element empty unless you "authenticate" that you are the owner of the video. You can still see all of YOUR video's keywords if you provide your **username** and **password** in the YouTubeRequestSettings constructor.

In .NET:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(appname, developerskey, username, password);
```

For PHP:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#ClientLogin_for_Installed_Applications

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really touched the Youtube API, but

```
<media:keywords/>
```

is an empty element. It means that there is no data for the element "media:keywords". My guess is that the the uploader hasn't specified any keywords for the video in question (these keywords are optional to all uploaders, which means that your script will have to deal with such occurrences).

After having a look at [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COwIYbYQUrQ&feature=g-vrec) in question (ID: COwIYbYQUrQ), I can see that my suspicions seem to be correct because the uploader hasn't actually specified any keywords.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply, Wayne
[br]
But, I'm actually the uploader and I set keywords on my videos.
[br]
You can try it on one of your videos if you want.
[br]
Thx

Comment: In the meantime, I tried the Client Login method which worked.
But it isn't safe as I have to write down my passwords in plain text.